# how to customize tooltip css

Tags: javascript, html, react-hooks, use-ref

I use useRef and This is part of my code:

```
 useEffect(() => {
      setRange(props.instrument);
      let data = getValues(props.instrument);
      tooltipRef.current.innerHTML = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
        showTooltip(data.LastTradePrice)
      );
    
  },[]);
```

and

```
const setRange = (instrument) => {
    let tooltip = tooltipRef.current;
const rangeInfo = getValues(instrument);
tooltip.children[0].style.left = `50%`;
tooltip.children[0].children[0].style.fill =
        rangeInfo.LastTradePrice > rangeInfo.PreviousDayPrice
          ? `${theme.palette.color.green}`
          : `${theme.palette.color.red}`;
 tooltip.setAttribute("title", rangeInfo.LastTradePrice);
}
```

and

```
const showTooltip = (data) => {
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
         
          <Grid
            item
            className={classes.currentPrice}
          >
            <LocationIcon
              className={clsx(
                classes.currentPriceIcon,
                device.isMobile && classes.currentPriceIconMobile
              )}
            ></LocationIcon>
          </Grid>
      
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  };
```

and

```
 return (
     <Grid item ref={tooltipRef}></Grid >
)
```

By default, it shows me a tooltip.How can I apply the style I want to this tooltip?
This is the default:

[image]

For example, how can I change the tooltip backgroundcolor?

Comment: You’ll have to use a custom tool tip component

Comment: Yes, but the tooltip tag doesn't run , but when I type setattribute, it displays the default tooltip